# Is "What would have happened if you were a few minutes later?" grammatical?

Tags: conditional-constructions, perfect-aspect

I read this sentence  in a movie

> What would have happened if you were a few minutes later?

I think that the sentence "What would have happened if you were a few minutes later?" is wrong grammatically.

Is it grammatical?

[image]

Comment: I think this question, referring to the same subtitle, has been asked previously, albeit in somewhat different form: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/107937/32

Comment: tsk, tsk... not the first time the user has recycled old questions without previously mentioning anything.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is awkward but not wrong.  But "...if you **had been** a few minutes later" sounds better.

Comment: Or, "What would have happened if you **had arrived** a few minutes later?"